# readMVar doesn't wake up on putMVar

Tags: multithreading, haskell, ghc

My code seems to be hanging on a `readMVar` after another thread calls `putMVar`. I wouldn't expect this to happen, but that's what I'm observing. My main thread creates two new threads, each with access to a shared `MVar` m.

Thread 1:

```
do
  putStrLn "tick"
  x <- readMVar m
  putStrLn "tock"
```

Thread 2:

```
do
  putMVar m 0
  putStrLn "put m0"
  void $ tryTakeMVar m
  putStrLn "take m"
  putMVar m 1
  putStrLn "put m1"
```

Main:

```
do
  m <- newEmptyMVar
  <start thread 1>
  <start thread 2>
```

In the following scenario, my program hangs:

Two threads have access to a shared MVar `m`, which is initially empty. Thread 1 blocks on `readMVar m`. Meanwhile, thread 2 calls `putMVar m ...`. At this point, thread 1 *could* proceed, but let's suppose it does not. Thread 2 then calls `tryTakeMVar m`, which presumably empties a full `MVar`. Then thread 2 again calls `putMVar m ...`. This scenario corresponds to the following output:

```
tick
put m0
take m
put m1
<hang>
```

What's going on here? I expect that "tock" should print, since thread 2 filled the MVar, but my program just hangs.

Comment: What version of GHC? In old ones, `readMVar` is a `takeMVar` followed by a `putMVar` (not performed atomically). If the `tryTakeMVar` and second `putMVar` happened between those, it would explain the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: I believe GHC 8.6.3, though it's a bit hard to tell when using Stack. Given your clean explanation, however, I'll try to dig a bit more into which version is being used.

Comment: Confirmed that it's GHC 8.6.3.

Comment: Here's the problem: I'm using strict-concurrency, which doesn't provide `tryReadMVar`. As a result, I implemented it myself using `tryTakeMVar` and `putMVar` (non-atomically). Thus what Daniel says is spot on.

Comment: You should write that up as an answer. That's good work tracking it down.

Answer (score 5):

I switched my MVar implementation from `base` to `strict-concurrency` while trying to debug a space leak. But as the question indicates, my code uses `tryReadMVar`, which is for some reason not provided by `strict-concurrency`. Thus, a while back, I implemented `tryReadMVar` myself like this:

```
tryReadMVar :: (NFData a) => MVar a -> IO (Maybe a)
tryReadMVar m = do
  mm <- tryTakeMVar m
  case mm of
    Nothing -> return ()
    Just a -> putMVar m a
  return mm
```

without really considering the implications. I had since forgotton all about doing this. As Daniel pointed out, old versions of `base` used to do something similar, but newer versions have an atomic `tryReadMVar` implementation. So even though I was using a new version of GHC, the problem was reintroduced as a result of using `strict-concurrency`.

Concurrently, the deadlock occurred in the following situation (which Daniel describes):

- thread 1 prints "tick"
- thread 2 puts the mvar using `putMVar`
- thread 2 prints "put m0"
- thread 1 takes the mvar using `tryTakeMVar` within `tryReadMVar`
- thread 2 takes the mvar using `tryTakeMVar`
- thread2 prints "take m"
- thread2 puts the mvar using `putMVar`
- thread2 prints "put m1"
- thread 1 deadlocks while trying to `putMVar` within `tryReadMVar`

Turns out that having an atomic `tryReadMVar` is useful!

Comment: I created an issue https://github.com/ygale/strict-concurrency/issues/2 with `strict-concurrency` requesting the addition of `tryReadMVar` so that other people don't make the same mistake.